# R stats::step function with forward direction param is not optimizing the LR model(AIC)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I've used AIC and step function for the variable selection before, but for some reason not able to get it to work.

```
library(ISLR)
d = data("Caravan")
train_data = Caravan[-c(1:500,]

m0 <- glm(Purchase ~ 1, data = train_data, family = "binomial")
stats::step(m0, direction = "forward", trace = 1 )
```

PN - I tried the `stepAIC` function and tried passing the scope as `scope = Purchase ~.,` but not those change solve the issue.

The output of the step function is a model that is the same as the base model(m0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue. As Onyambu mentioned in his reply, in AIC, the dot doesn't work the way it does in lm. Instead of concatenating the 84 predictors manually, I used the paste function with collapse="+".

```
glmnet( formula(paste0("Y~", paste(names(Caravan)[1:85], collapse="+"))), 
                       ....)
```

Answer (score 2):

`step` function uses `update` within it. On the other hand, the `.` has a different meaning in the `update` function as compared to the `lm` function. The `.` in update is used to indicate that you would like to MAINTAIN the formula the way it was originally rather than used to INCLUDE ALL THE VARIABLES as in `lm`. thus if your model is `m<-lm(y~x)`, `update(m,log(.)~.)` simply means change the left hand side to log, ie `log(y)` while maintaining the right hand side as it is. ie `x`. The perios does not include any other variables other than the ones in the model already.

WHAT YOU SHOULD DO:

```
scopef <- reformulate(grep("Purchase",names(Caravan),value=T,invert = T),"Purchase")
step(m0,scopef,direction = "forward")
```

Comment: Thanks, @Onyambu. Really appreciate your detailed reply.